# JSF Environment Setup

Tags: java, maven, jsf, tomcat

I am reading **tutorials point** on how to setup Environment for JSF.

The MAVEN works.

[image]

The APACHE works.

[image]

I followed all the steps and configured all the *environment variables* required.

Next step, I open the command prompt and typed the following command.

[image]

And receives these errors.

Comment: yes sir. What are the possible reasons why it fails to build?

Comment: I just read the Maven output. First thing which catches my eye is that it said "SpringMVCExample" while you clearly said you wanted to setup a JSF project (Spring MVC is a full competitor of JSF and absolutely not the same). But alas. Next thing is that Maven was very helpful in telling that you can re-run it with -e switch to see the full stack trace of these errors. Last thing is that there's even a link about the errors and possible solutions.  I have a hard time in understanding how exactly you found it unclear and why exactly you haven't even *tried* the -e switch and/or opening the link.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are following the tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.htm. It shows this Maven command:

```
C:\JSF>mvn archetype:create 
-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test 
-DartifactId=helloworld 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

It is confusing. You have to write it in one line:

```
C:\JSF>mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Or use the caret(`^`) symbol:

```
C:\JSF>mvn archetype:create ^
-DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test ^ 
-DartifactId=helloworld ^
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried and I'm still having same build errors but instead of "BuildingMVCExample" it changed to "Building Maven Stub Project (NO POM) 1". Are there any files must be placed inside the folder of JSF?

Comment: JSF folder should be empty because you want to create a new maven project from a maven archetype. Are you sure you are writing the complete line? Could you paste here the exact line you are writing? Maven should cretae the new project without errors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the installation step # 9 because I set my environment variable CATALINA_HOME as C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24.
Should I also add CATALINA_HOME to the PATH of my system?

Comment: I found some configuration on the net but do you think doing it is necessary? http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it first time. Try this:

As you can see here http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/plugin-info.html
`create` goal is deprecated. Use `generate` instead.

On the other hand your `JAVA_HOME` variable must point to a JDK, not to a public JRE, so change your variable value:

`JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51`

It will be neccesary for Maven when compiling your java code.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I'm newbie. I did it because I thought it was a different solution, unrelated with my first one, but it is not clear, so I should have updated it, I agree.

Comment: Technically, OP should have asked a new question based on the new error, but as long as OP stubbornly ignores Maven's advice how to figure out the actual error, OP will keep chameleonizing the question until OP gets everything to work as intented.